# how to start an action after the webpage is loaded using struts2

Tags: javascript, struts2

Is there a way to perform an submit action on a page after the page is loaded, whit out using a button or a submit form.

I need this to populate my web page whit data from database and using a Java class. For the moment i can do this, but i am using a form to submit and my data appears on table only after i hit the button.

I just want to appear when the page is loaded. Can someone give some suggestion ?

**struts.xml**

```
    <action name="afisusers" class="eu.memshare.payments.action.ListaUsers">
        <result name="succes">users.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

**page.jsp**

```
    <s:action="afisusers"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can initate an ajax request on load of the page or use jQuery's $.ajax function (I would recommend this).

To include jQuery you can use the script hosted on [Google CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide). put this in the  head tag of your page.

```
<head>
<!-- .... other stuff ....  -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    submitForm();
});

function submitForm(){
   $.ajax({
      url : '/afisusers.action',
      data : $("#form").serialize(),
      success : function(data){
          //do what you want here.
          alert("form submitted");
      }
   });
}
 </script>
<!-- .... other stuff ....  -->
</head>
```

replace "#form" with # + your form id.

specific to struts, you can return the response as a json object or a jsp.  the JSON object data will contain whatever you return from the action.

If you are using a browser like chrome, right click and hit inspect element. you will see the javascript errors that you are getting.

Comment: can you make a small example, because i am quit new at this and don't know how exactly i can do this

Comment: have added an example. do let me know if it works. would be happy to help.

Comment: ok i have used your example on my webpage , but still didn't work , i've included script you gave me and i also done this  <--<body onload="submitForm()">-->

Comment: I've done this exactly as you describe it  but still didn't manage to submit the form. i am using mozilla as a browser

Comment: i need more details. what is the error you are getting? did you inspect the element in your browser?

Comment: i am geting this error  [09:20:35.267] SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate source map URL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead @ http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js:1

Comment: after few hours debugging my webpage i've found a typo error , now it works ok.

Comment: great. happy to hear that.